# I am trying to merge data based on their dates

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I am trying to achieve the following data frame format.
The first dataset is the results data with the date in a DateTime format whereas the second dataset is the rank_date in an object format. How do I merge the data based on their dates?

```
rank = rank.set_index(['rank_date']).groupby(['country_full'], group_keys=False).resample('D').first().fillna(method='ffill').reset_index()
```

This is the following error I get:

**TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'**

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Probably, **rank_date**'s type is string-object, not **datetime**:

```
rank['rank_date']=pd.to_datetime(rank['rank_date'])
rank = rank.set_index(['rank_date']).groupby(['country_full'], group_keys=False).resample('D').first().fillna(method='ffill').reset_index()
```